# Ionic/Cordova and Arduino bluetooth

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, arduino, hm-10

I'm building an app with Ionic, and I am trying to send a simple string from an arduino to my app with [bluetoothLE](https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE).

I'm using an Arduino with a HM-10 bluetooth adapter, I managed to connect and disconnect to the device, but cannot understand how to send or receive data.

Just to test it, I've been trying the write method and have a simple script on the arduino looking for any kind of data via serial communication, but without success.

this is the method i am using:

```
$rootScope.writeH =function(address, serviceUuid, characteristicUuid, value) {
    var string = "H";
    var bytes = bluetoothle.stringToBytes(string);
    var encodedString = bluetoothle.bytesToEncodedString(encodedString);

    var params = {address:address, serviceUuid:serviceUuid, characteristicUuid:characteristicUuid, value:encodedString};

    console.log("Write : " + JSON.stringify(params));

    $cordovaBluetoothLE.write(params).then(writeSuccess, writeError);
}
```

And this is how I call the function:

```
<div class="col">
  <a class="button button-balanced button-small" ng-click="writeH(selectedDevice.address, selectedService.uuid, selectedCharacteristic.uuid)">Write H</a>
</div>
```

I'm using an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.

This is my Arduino sketch, at this point I'm just trying to get ANY data:

```
char val; // variable to receive data from the serial port
int ledpin = 8; // LED connected to pin 48 (on-board LED)

void setup() {

  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);  // pin 8 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
  Serial.begin(9600);       // start serial communication at 9600bps
}

void loop() {

  if( Serial.available() )       // if data is available to read
  {
    val = Serial.read();         // read it and store it in 'val'
  }
  if( val == NULL )               // if any NO data was received
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);  //  LED is OFF
  } else { 
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);   // otherwise turn it ON
    delay(2000);
  }
  delay(100);                    // wait 100ms for next reading
}
```

Edit:

I'm using a HM10 chip, I just tried this app: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hm10-bluetooth-serial/id1030454675?mt=8 and it worked perfectly, just had to change the setting to "write without response" - I'm not sure what kind of write I'm using in my javascript, and that could be the issue, as "write with response" will not work.

Edit 2:

Just checked the source files for iOS from the bluetooth cordova plugin and the write type is set to no response, so it's not that...

```
//Write Type
NSString *const writeTypeNoResponse = @"noResponse";
```

Console Log:

```
[Log] Initialize : {"request":true} (index.js, line 58)
[Log] Initialize Success : {"status":"enabled"} (index.js, line 64)
[Log] Enabled (index.js, line 68)
[Log] Start Scan : {"serviceUuids":[],"allowDuplicates":false} (index.js, line 129)
[Log] Start Scan Success : {"status":"scanStarted"} (index.js, line 135)
[Log] Scan Started (index.js, line 145)
[Log] Start Scan Success : {"status":"scanResult","advertisement":"zgAG1R1JwPI=","rssi":-54,"name":"Avea_6C73","address":"4BED6ECD-A5A9-6625-61A6-D693B02EAC78"} (index.js, line 135)
[Log] Scan Result (index.js, line 139)
[Log] Start Scan Success : {"status":"scanResult","advertisement":"SE30uF7wPYo=","rssi":-82,"name":"HMSoft","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 135)
[Log] Scan Result (index.js, line 139)
[Log] Connect : {"address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 302)
[Log] Connect Success : {"name":"HMSoft","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B","status":"connecting"} (index.js, line 308)
[Log] Connecting (index.js, line 316)
[Log] Connect Success : {"name":"HMSoft","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B","status":"connected"} (index.js, line 308)
[Log] Connected (index.js, line 312)
[Log] Discover : {"address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 417)
[Log] Discover Success : {"status":"discovered","services":[{"characteristics":[{"descriptors":[{"descriptorUuid":"2902"},{"descriptorUuid":"2901"}],"properties":{"writeWithoutResponse":true,"read":true,"notify":true},"characteristicUuid":"ffe1"}],"serviceUuid":"ffe0"}],"name":"HMSoft","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 423)
[Log] Discovered (index.js, line 427)
[Log] Write Descriptor : {"address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B","characteristicUuid":"ffe1","descriptorUuid":"2901","value":""} (index.js, line 879)
[Log] Read Descriptor Error : {"message":"Service not found","name":"HMSoft","error":"service","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 868)
[Log] Write Descriptor : {"address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B","characteristicUuid":"ffe1","descriptorUuid":"2902","value":""} (index.js, line 879)
[Log] Read Descriptor Error : {"message":"Service not found","name":"HMSoft","error":"service","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 868)
[Log] Subscribe : {"address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B","serviceUuid":"ffe0","characteristicUuid":"ffe1"} (index.js, line 757)
[Log] Subscribe Success : {"status":"subscribed","characteristicUuid":"ffe1","name":"HMSoft","serviceUuid":"ffe0","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 763)
[Log] Subscribed (index.js, line 771)
[Log] Write Descriptor : {"address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B","characteristicUuid":"ffe1","descriptorUuid":"2901","value":""} (index.js, line 879)
[Log] Read Descriptor Error : {"message":"Service not found","name":"HMSoft","error":"service","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 868)
[Log] Write : {"address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B","serviceUuid":"ffe0","characteristicUuid":"ffe1","value":""} (index.js, line 823)
[Log] Write Error : {"message":"Write value not found","name":"HMSoft","error":"write","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 843)
```

Comment: have you paired your phone with your arduino ?

Comment: not through the settings on the iPhone, as the phone cannot detect the bluetooth outside the app, i think that when I press "connect" inside the app, it pairs to the device, and small red led on the bluetooth stops blinking.

Comment: and also after hitting connect on the app, I get info about the bluetooth module, like Uuid and characteristics - this means the devices are paired right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to discover services and characteristics before send and read data. Use bluetoothle.discover

Comment: I'm using the example app: 
https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE/tree/master/example/www

So i opened the app and did:
Initialize - Start Scan - Device name - Connect - Discover(you were right) - ffe0 - ffe1 

Now I have two descriptors "uuid" : 2901 and 2902, tried to write to both and nothing happens...

Comment: just to check, all I want is to have serial communication like the one you have between an arduino and a computer with bluetooth, I am bit confused with this...

Comment: Your Javascript seem correct . I think the issue could comme from your arduino code.
Did you do the correct setting. are you sure that your communication with the characteristic must pass by serial com?
What BLE chip are you using with your arduino?

Comment: I'm using a HM10 chip, I just tried this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hm10-bluetooth-serial/id1030454675?mt=8 and it worked perfectly, just had to change the setting to "write without response" - im not sure what kind of write im using in my javascript, and that could be the issue, as "write with response" will not work - just tried deleting the ".then(writeSuccess, writeError)" from "$cordovaBluetoothLE.write(params).then(writeSuccess, writeError);" with no luck... - also deleted the same bit of code from the write function.. also no luck...

Comment: You are using HM-10 with arduino. it's seem that you dont set the bluetooth correctly. According to this [link]( https://bellcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/android-and-arduino-bluetooth-communication/). you might init Bluetooth for Serial communication.

Comment: im going to try that sketch, although its strange since the other app worked with my sketch...

Comment: tried the sketch, both apps stopped working... - im almost sure that it is the "kind" of write

Comment: use    var params = {address:address, serviceUuid:serviceUuid, characteristicUuid:characteristicUuid, value:encodedString,type:"noResponse"};

Comment: now im looking the console log from the app, and there are no errors, the method is working as it should... im just not doing it right

Comment: just added a log above, for some reason the value is empty

Comment: Ok I changed the arduino sketch to send data instead of waiting to receive, and as soon as I hit subscribe in the app I receive the arduino messages, just cant send messages to the arduino... wtf...

Comment: lol have you add to write params the property type:"noResponse" . if yes it very strange

Comment: [Log] Write : {"address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B","serviceUuid":"ffe0","characteristicUuid":"ffe1","value":"encodedString","type":"noResponse"} (index.js, line 828)
[Log] Write Error : {"message":"Write value not found","name":"HMSoft","error":"write","address":"07929248-D56A-1FDB-9036-D012FBC4F10B"} (index.js, line 848)

Comment: but just an absurd question, does the characteristic is writable?  "properties": {
            "write": true,
            "writeWithoutResponse": true,
            "read": true
          }